# Display data from SharePoint Online document library on Powerapp

Tags: azure, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, azure-logic-apps, powerapps

I am looking for the best solution to get the documents from SharePoint online document library and display them on a website or power app.  The website or app will be used by anonymous users. I worked on the Powerapp and was able to display the documents from SharePoint but when we deploy the app then it asks for authentication. How can this be avoided?

Can this be achieved by azure logic app?
Many thanks,
Rajesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Canvas and Model app require a licensed user account.  You can look at creating a powerapps portal and build a custom control in the portal to display the sharepoint items.